# Replacing scrolling with easing animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I have been trying hard to replace the default `$(window).scroll()` behavior with beautiful easing animation. But no luck so far. Following is my code.

```
$(window).scroll(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var cp=$(window).scrollTop(); // current scroll position

    //animate with custom easing
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:cp}, 50,'easeInElastic');

});
```

But this is not working. It simply scrolls 1-3 pixels only and very slow.

If i change it to `$('html, body').animate({scrollTop:500}, 50,'easeInElastic');`
it just does it once and thats not what i want.

I want the replace the standard scroll behavior with easing animation when user presses the scroll-bar buttons.

JSFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/bfDrp/

Comment: possible to provide fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this plugin:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Here is implemintation:

```
<script>
(function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("body").mCustomScrollbar();
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: I dont want to change the scrollbars....but i want to change the behavior of scrolling amount and animation. I want it to animate with easing animation.

Answer (score 0):

> Use .scrollTo function at the place of that you can also use scrollX
>   and scrollY  with window.

```
window.scrollTo(0,150,500);
```

Comment: But how to add animation in the window.scrollTo

Comment: .scrollTo(x,y,delay_time); it is jquery function it will work